# Округление дробных чисел. С++

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T> struct Test
{
    T value;
    Test(T valueOfUser = 0):value(valueOfUser) {}
    Test<T> operator * (float k) {return Test<T>(value*k);}
};

int main()
{
    Test<int> t(5);
    Test<int> t1= t*1.999999;
    std::cout << t1.value; // 9
    return 0;
}
```

Можно ли сделать так,чтобы округлялось в большую или меньшую сторону в зависимости от полученного значения , только тогда, когда у меня тип `int`. С `float` и `double` округлять конечно не надо

Comment: Можно написать специализацию для типа int, можно сделать проверку в операторе. Проверка с помощью `std::is_same_v<T, int>`, округление с помощью функций из <cmath> (round, floor, ceil)

Comment: @cppquestions `if (std::is_same<T,int>::value) return Test<int>(value*k + 0.5)`?

Comment: есть еще и старый способ (typeid(T) == typeid(int))

Comment: @Kaznachei да, но лучше if constexpr

Comment: А где планируется задавать в какую сторону округлять? И округлять где, при выводе или при инициализации?

Answer (score 1):

Например, [такой вариант](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FHFN4kqRO7njT0Ho) (с++17):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct Test
{
    T value;
    Test(T valueOfUser = 0):value(valueOfUser) {}
    Test<T> operator * (double k) {
        if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>)
            return Test<T>(std::lround(value*k));
        else
            return Test<T>(value*k);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test<int> t(5);
    Test<int> t1= t*1.999999;
    std::cout << t1.value; // 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверить можно [здесь](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Q327nWVYiuCtdBrs).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template<typename T>
class basic_wrapper {
public:
    explicit basic_wrapper(const T& value)
        : value_(value)
    {}

protected:
    T value_;

    template<typename U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const basic_wrapper<U>& w) {
        return (s << w.value_);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class wrapper : public basic_wrapper<T> {
public:
    explicit wrapper(const T& value)
        : basic_wrapper<T>(value)
    {}

    template<typename U>
    friend wrapper operator*(const wrapper& w, U k) {
        return wrapper(static_cast<T>(w.value_ * k));
    }
};

template<>
class wrapper<int> : public basic_wrapper<int> {
public:
    explicit wrapper(int value)
        : basic_wrapper(value)
    {}

    template<typename U>
    friend wrapper operator*(const wrapper& w, U k) {
        return wrapper(static_cast<int>(std::floor(w.value_ * k)));
    }
};

using integer_wrapper = wrapper<int>;

int main() {
    integer_wrapper w { 100 };
    std::cout << (w * 1.2019) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```